# How to add horizontal carousel above List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to recreate the layout of the native Watch app which has a carousel with a `List` underneath it. How can get the carousel in the first section to scroll off the edges of the screen instead of cut off?

[image]

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
let data: [String] = (0..<25).map { "Item \($0)" }
let data2: [String] = (0..<3).map { "Item \($0)" }

NavigationView {
    List {
        Section {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(data) { element in
                        VStack {
                            Text(element)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        .listRowInsets(.init())
        Section("Section 1") {
            ForEach(data2) { element in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Destination")
                } label: {
                    Label(element, systemImage: "calendar.circle.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .searchable(text: .constant(""), placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
    .navigationTitle("Watch")
}
```

This is the native watch app I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

Comment: Try using `Form` instead of `List`. If that doesn't work, post a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried replacing `List` with `Form` but has the same effect; the carousel truncates at the edges. The code in the question is runnable and reproducible even with demo data.

Comment: What do you means scroll off the screen instead of cut off ? I do not understand what you mean ?

Comment: The horizontal carousel does not extend until the edges of the screen. Instead there’s horizontal padding I can’t get rid of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I made a SwiftUI List full width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545832/how-can-i-made-a-swiftui-list-full-width)